# Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Class<capture<?>>' to 'java.lang.Class<T>

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to write the following method in my super class:

```
public <T extends Downloader> T getDownloader(Context context, Integer... positions) throws Exception {

    Class<T> mClass = (Class<T>)Class.forName(getDownloaderClassName());
    T downloader = mClass.cast(mClass.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(context));
    if (downloader != null)
        downloader.setPositions(positions);

    return downloader;
}
```

Yet, I don't know how to avoid AndroidStudio telling me

```
Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Class<capture<?>>' to 'java.lang.Class<T>
```

Either I get it regarding the first line, or, if I change

```
Class<T> to Class<?>
```

Then I have to perform a direct cast

```
(T)mClass.getConstructors....
```

To be more precise, this super class is abstract, and getDownloaderClassName() is actually defined as follows:

```
public abstract String getDownloaderClassName();
```

So that the daughter classes can choose with descendant of Downloader they need to retrieve using getDownloader().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess I am confused between T and ?, So I found a warning free way of doing it:

```
   public Downloader getDownloader(Context context, Integer... positions) throws Exception {

    Class<? extends Downloader> mClass = getDownloaderClassName();
    Downloader downloader = mClass.cast(mClass.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(context));
    if (downloader != null)
        downloader.setPositions(positions);

    return downloader;
}

public abstract Class<? extends Downloader> getDownloaderClassName();
```

and then, the abstract method just becomes:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends Downloader> getDownloaderClassName() {
    return DemoDownloader.class;
}
```

in the descendants.

I guess I'll just have to cast the result of getDownloader when I need specific fields or methods.

Answer (score 0):

The signature `public <T extends Downloader> T getDownloader(Context context, Integer... positions)` is not type safe. It makes `getDownloader` a generic method, which means that it must work correctly no matter what the caller wants `T` to be, *without knowing what `T` is*. Note that `T` does not show up in any of the parameter types. This means that the same exact call with the same exact arguments, must somehow return type `Downloader1` if that's what one caller wants and also return type `Downloader2` if that's what another caller wants, without the `getDownloader` method having any information about what the caller wants! This is clearly impossible, unless `getDownloader` always returns `null`.

The signature `public Downloader getDownloader(Context context, Integer... positions)` is different, because it says that the `getDownloader` method returns type `Downloader`. Your `getDownloader` method chooses the type of the thing to return (as long as it's a subtype of `Downloader`); the caller doesn't choose the type, and cannot make any assumptions about the thing returned except that it's an instance of `Downloader`. That is type safe.